# Splitting up a rather complex string, need assistance

Tags: php

I have a string that is something like this:

```
../../FolderName$Username$Password
```

I need to split these three things (Path to folder, username, and password) each into their own variables, and I'm having a bit of trouble.

```
$path = substr($_REQUEST["filename"],0, strpos($_REQUEST["filename"],'$',0)); //Gets the filepath SUCCESSFULLY

$username = substr($_REQUEST["filename"],strpos($_REQUEST["filename"],'$',0),strpos($realtmp,'$',strpos($_REQUEST["filename"],'$',0))); 

//Error, can't get the username properly, it is empty so I probably have a syntax error, but in general I don't know how to structure it.
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expression is the best way to solve this... The regular expression capture group [1] consists of everything up to but not including the first instance of "$". The capture group [2] works the same, capturing everything up to but not including the second instance of "$". Capture group [3] includes everything to end of string.

```
<?php
  $Filename= 'filename$username$password';
  preg_match('/([^$]*)[$]([^$]*)[$]([^$]*)/', $Filename, $re);
  $File = $re[1];
  $Username = $re[2];
  $Password = $re[3];
  echo "File:{$File}\n";
  echo "Username:{$Username}\n";
  echo "Password:{$Password}\n";
?>
```

Edit: However, as stated in other answers, it is never recommended to store passwords as plain text

Edit 2: the ([^$]*) means you are "capturing a group" of "everything up to the $" character.

Comment: Thanks, the password is put into a hashed format prior to use.

Comment: Can you explain the preg_match line a bit more for me please?

I may not always use '$' as the character to separate the information, if I wanted to swap it to lets say a: * character instead, how would it change?

Likewise it can't match any characters that are likely to be found in a username or password.

Comment: I'd recommend playing with a regular expression eval tool: https://regexr.com/ However, if you want to know... basically the ([^$]*) means you are "capturing a group" of "everything except the $" character. then you are stating you want the "$" character out of the capture group by putting it after the capture group...

Comment: So if I just swapped all occurrences of '$' in the preg_match with '&' for example, it would still work the same, no?

Also thanks, your code is much cleaner than what I had, even though I did solve it on my own.

Comment: Updated my comment. Accidentally clicked enter ;P

Comment: Or you could use `explode( '$', $string )` it is way faster, less complex and more efficient compared to a regular expression as there is only a single and the same delimiter. See manual [PHP explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). Moreover, if you are using regular expression special, meta characters like $ although they are syntactically inside square brackets make sure to escape them, just in case, and for clarity.